# Tool, library, database or API for my OSM based application

Tags: c#, openstreetmap, geocoding

I have build an dotnet 6.0 REST API that retrieves upcoming and passed objects based on a users position. I use nominatim to get an `OSM_Id` from a users' `lat`/`lon`. I then use that `OSM_ID` to query my database to find objects that are located on that same way. All these objects have a latitude and a longitude. So before I inserted them in the database I reverse geocoded those coordinates to get an `OSM_id` for each object. This works all fine, no problems here.

The problem arises when no objects in my database are linked (by `OSM_id`) to the osm object (way) where the user is current located on. I then have to find the next way and previous way that has an object linked to it. This is the tricky part because `Nominatim` does not give you relations or nodes.

I have "solved" this by downloading the ways, nodes, and relations with type restriction from overpass and insert them in my database. This made it possible for me to find adjacent ways. The `Overpass` query I use is this one:

```
    [out:json];
    area["ISO3166-1" = "NL"][admin_level=2];
    (
        way["highway"~"^(motorway|trunk|primary|motorway_link|trunk_link|primary_link)$"]["ref"="{0}"](area);
        relation["type"="restriction"](bw);
    );
    (._;>;);
    out;
```

The problem however is that it is near impossible to update. And the script I have written to insert all that information into my database takes hours to be completed.

Is there a (preferably offline, similar to nominatim with the updates and stuff) tool, library, API that can very quickly give me a way and it's adjacent ways? The tool / library also needs to automatically update to the latest osm file. Manually is also okay if all I have to do is download the latest file.